# IIS and Visual Studio is having different result

Tags: iis

```
http://localhost:72/Home/Support?_subject=&_category=&_reportedDateFrom=09%2F05%2F2013&_reportedDateTo=09%2F05%2F2013&_solvedDateFrom=&_solvedDateTo=&_status=
```

Above is the pre-setup IIS website .. the date filtering is not filtering correctly.

```
http://localhost:54550/Home/Support?_subject=&_category=&_reportedDateFrom=09%2F05%2F2013&_reportedDateTo=09%2F05%2F2013&_solvedDateFrom=&_solvedDateTo=&_status=
```

Above is the visual studio debug URL, just the port number is different and it's working perfectly.

I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Is it possible that two different versions of the program exist at those two locations?

Comment: is this asp.net? mvc? web.api?

Answer (score 1):

To debug this I would start with the following:

- Do a clean and rebuild of your solution.
- Make sure you don't have two copies of the application running.
- Make sure the application is being hosted in IIS properly. (Does the app show up when you right click and browse the web site from the IIS manager)
- Attach the debugger to the process running under IIS in order to inspect the query parameters.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37182/Debug-your-ASP-NET-Application-while-Hosted-on-IIS) is getting a bit old but it has the general procedure you need to follow to attach to IIS to inspect a process.